# How do I crop portions of large image to an ImageView

Tags: android, imageview, crop

Say I have an image that looks like the one to the left...
Each flag is 30x20px.

How do I display the area 0,60 to 30,80? I would also like to be able so upscale it afterwards.
[image: Example]

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method to create another bitmap from your offset

```
/**
 * Returns an immutable bitmap from the specified subset of the source
 * bitmap. The new bitmap may be the same object as source, or a copy may
 * have been made. It is initialized with the same density as the original
 * bitmap.
 *
 * @param source   The bitmap we are subsetting
 * @param x        The x coordinate of the first pixel in source
 * @param y        The y coordinate of the first pixel in source
 * @param width    The number of pixels in each row
 * @param height   The number of rows
 * @return A copy of a subset of the source bitmap or the source bitmap itself.
 * @throws IllegalArgumentException if the x, y, width, height values are
 *         outside of the dimensions of the source bitmap, or width is <= 0,
 *         or height is <= 0
 */
public static Bitmap createBitmap(Bitmap source, int x, int y, int width, int height) {
    return createBitmap(source, x, y, width, height, null, false);
}
```

Another option is create a custom ImageView, then override `onDraw()` method to draw bitmap on `Canvas` from your offsets

Use this method of `Canvas` class

```
public void drawBitmap(@NonNull Bitmap bitmap, float left, float top, @Nullable Paint paint) { }
```